# Excel columns of several worksheets - copy, sort, hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

Need some help with the following:

I have several worksheets with the same structure and within each worksheet I have two columns (let's call them X & Y) that I need to copy with their cellvalues (letter-number combination) and also copy the values of Column A-F to an own sheet for X and Y.

On the "new" sheet I want to put X/Y to column A sort the values after A and attach a constant hyperlink to each cellvalue in A.
So X or Y goes to A and A-F to B-G.

Then I want to make column F or the new G clickable so that it will take me to the row in the according worksheet.
X and Y don't always happen to be in column X or Y but I think this can be solved with a "name search".

When I execute my code then for example worksheet3 will overwrite the values of worksheet1 and my hyperlink structure is wrong too. The sorting is left out since that is working.

```
Function CopyAndSort(ByRef mySheet As Worksheet)
'   If mySheet.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
'   Exit Function
'   End If

   mySheet.Activate
    Set sheetCS = Sheets("CopyAndSort Sheet")
    sheetCS.Range("A:A").Value = ""
   lastRowCS = Range("X:X").Cells.Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Row

     rowNumber = 1
    For rowCopy = 5 To lastRowFO
        sheetCopy = Range("BE" & rowCopy)
        If Trim(sheetCopy) <> "" Then
            sheetCopy = Replace(sheetCopy, """", "")
            If InStr(1, sheetCopy, ",", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
               sheetCopyArray = Split(sheetCopy, ",")
            Else
               sheetCopyArray = Array(sheetCopy)
      End If

            For Each copy In sheetCopyArray

                rowNumber = rowNumber + 1

                        copy_Value = copy
' test for url                         
'  sheetCS.Cells(rowNumber, 1).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""ConstURL & copyValue"")"

                     sheetCS.Cells(rowNumber, 1) = copy_Value
                        copy_Value = Cells(rowCopy, 1)
                            sheetCS.Cells(rowNumber, 2) = copy_Value
                        copy_Value = Cells(rowCopy, 2)
                            sheetCS.Cells(rowNumber, 3) = copy_Value
                        copy_Value = Cells(rowCopy, 3)
                            sheetCS.Cells(rowNumber, 4) = copy_Value
                            copy_Value = Cells(rowCopy, 4)
                            sheetCS.Cells(rowNumber, 5) = copy_Value
                        copy_Value = Cells(rowCopy, 5)
                            sheetCS.Cells(rowNumber, 6) = copy_Value

            Next
        End If

    Next
```

So how can I manage to not overwrite the values and attach the correct hyperlink syntax, plus making colum G clickable?
And can I use one function for X and Y?
Some code examples would help me alot. 
Thank you.

**UPDATE**:

i forgot to mention that X & Y will always be next to each other.

Example:

Sheet1:

```
|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|ColF|....|ColX|ColY|
```

Sheet2: here "ColX" is in ColQ and ColY in ColR

```
|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|ColF|....|ColXinColQ|ColYinColR|
```

CopySheet_of_X: now copy ColX plus ColA-ColF of Sheet1 and do the same for Sheet2 where X is in ColQ

**Output for both sheets:**
    |ColX|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|ColF|

CopySheet_of_Y: now copy ColY plus ColA-ColF of Sheet1 and do the same for Sheet2 where Y is in ColR

**Output for both sheets:**
    |ColY|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|ColF|

Hyperlink:
so now the values of ColX and ColY should be concatenated with a preceding hyperlink:
If a cell in ColX has the value of "someValue1" then it should be turned into myurl://sometext=someValue1

and I don't know the right way to jump back to the row when clicking on ColF.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Can you show us an example?

Comment: CopySheet_of_X sheet will have data from both sheets or there will be 2 sheets - CopySheet_of_X1, CopySheet_of_X2?

Comment: just one "output" sheet for X and one for Y with the above columns of Sheet1 and Sheet2. If there are more "input" sheets in the spreadsheet then those should also be added to the two output sheets.

Comment: So CopySheet_of_X should look like this after data import from the 2 sheets `|ColX|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|ColF|ColX|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|ColF|`? I hope you see where my confusion lies?

Comment: not like that.
this would be the wanted output for both sheets:
|ColX|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|ColF|

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13727/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-tonyc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Paste this in a module and run Sub Sample.

```
Option Explicit

Const hLink As String = "d3://d3explorer/idlist="

Sub Sample()
    Dim sheetsToProcess

    Set sheetsToProcess = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))

    CopyData sheetsToProcess, "CopySheet_of_X", "FirstLinkValue"

    '~~> Similarly for Y
    'CopyData sheetsToProcess, "CopySheet_of_Y", "SecondLinkValue"
End Sub

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
'                      USAGE                         '
' wsI      : Worksheet Collection                    '
' wsONm    : name of the new sheet for output        '
' XY       : Name of the X or Y Header               '
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
Sub CopyData(wsI, wsONm As String, XY As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sSheet As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, LastRow As Long, lCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MyAr() As String

    '~~> Delete the Output sheet if it is already there
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets(wsONm).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Recreate the output sheet
    Set ws = Sheets.Add: ws.Name = wsONm

    '~~> Create Headers in Output Sheet
    ws.Range("A1") = XY
    wsI(1).Range("A3:F3").Copy ws.Range("B1")

    '~~> Loop throught the sheets array
    For Each sSheet In wsI
        LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With Sheets(sSheet.Name)
            '~~> Find the column which has X/Y header
            Set aCell = .Rows(3).Find(What:=XY, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If aCell Is Nothing Then
                '~~> If not found, inform and exit
                MsgBox XY & " was not found in " & .Name, vbCritical, "Exiting Application"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                '~~> if found then get the column number
                lCol = aCell.Column

                '~~> Identify the last row of the sheet
                lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                '~~> Loop through the X Column and split values
                For i = 4 To lRow
                    If InStr(1, .Cells(i, lCol), ",") Then '<~~ If values like A1,A2,A3
                        MyAr = Split(.Cells(i, lCol), ",")

                        For j = 0 To UBound(MyAr)
                            '~~> Add hyperlink in Col 1
                            With ws
                                .Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = MyAr(j)
                                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(LastRow, 1), Address:= _
                                hLink & .Cells(LastRow, 1).Value, TextToDisplay:=.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value
                            End With

                            .Range("A" & i & ":F" & i).Copy ws.Range("B" & LastRow)

                            '~~> Add hyperlink in Col 2
                            With ws
                                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(LastRow, 7), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                                sSheet.Name & "!" & "A" & i, TextToDisplay:=.Cells(LastRow, 7).Value
                            End With

                            LastRow = LastRow + 1
                        Next j
                    Else  '<~~ If values like A1
                        '~~> Add hyperlink in Col 1
                        With ws
                            .Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = Sheets(sSheet.Name).Cells(i, lCol)
                            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(LastRow, 1), Address:= _
                            hLink & .Cells(LastRow, 1).Value, TextToDisplay:=.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value
                        End With

                        .Range("A" & i & ":F" & i).Copy ws.Range("B" & LastRow)

                        '~~> Add hyperlink in Col 2
                        With ws
                            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(LastRow, 7), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                            sSheet.Name & "!" & "A" & i, TextToDisplay:=.Cells(LastRow, 7).Value
                        End With

                        LastRow = LastRow + 1
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        End With
    Next

    '~~> Sort the data
    ws.Columns("A:G").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Siddharth: I managed to integrate your sub to my macro. One thing that I would like to change is to leave out the copying of rows that don't have a LinkValue, because a) that will copy unnecessary data and b) the sub throws an error if there's a blank Link cell. Also when copying, is there a way to remove the formatting of my sheets (background-color, borders, etc.) and maybe set a certain size for width and height of each cell in the output sheets? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, so I just put  **If Len(.Cells(i, lCol)) > 0 Then** that seems to do the trick for empty link cells